# setTimeout keeps firing

Tags: javascript, dom, settimeout

I have a simple chrome extension, which works with page's DOM (it looks for "something" what looks like login forms). Problem is, that many pages has "dynamic" login forms - its code is loded when needed. That's why body's onload event is not enough.

So I've created mutation observer and execute my procedure each time DOM changes (there will be some restrictions in the future - many of these changes does not affect my purpose)

Because of some intervals I have to implement delayed execution of my procedure over updated DOM (the time 500 is only for testing purpose)

```
var target = document.body;
var timer;

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {

  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    var count = mutation.addedNodes.length;

    if( count > 0) { 

        timer = setTimeout(function (){

                   console.log("executed");
                   my_procedure();

               }, 500);

    }
  });    
});

var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

observer.observe(target, config);
```

The problem is, that setTimeout keeps firing to infinity, which makes the page pretty lazy after some time. In Chrome JS console is number of 'executed' messages still increasing.

I'm aware of `clearTimeout(timer)`, but I'm not able to use it right - so `my_procedure` is executed only once for each DOM change.

EDIT: `my_procedure` is actually 3rd-party library function, so I don't want (or can) to change it - the function starts the whole form-classification logic.

Thank yout for advice.

Comment: What do `my_procedure()` do?

Comment: forEach() will loop ur action.. So setTimeout is triggering many times

Comment: `my_procedure` is not actually mine - I've wanted to demonstrate, that its code is working and I only have to handle its calling. Made an edit note to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my_procedure() you can use

```
clearTimeout(timer);
```

in the first line to avoid multiple occurence

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
var target = document.body;
var timer;
var counter = 0;

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {

  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    var count = mutation.addedNodes.length;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    if( count > 0) { 
        if(counter == 0){
        counter = 1;
        timer = setTimeout(function (){
                   console.log("executed");
                   my_procedure();

               }, 500);
        }else {
            clearTimeout(timer);
         }

    }
  });    
});

var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

observer.observe(target, config);
```

Comment: I'm sorry for making an incorrect name for this procedure - I actually can't (at least don't wish to) change its code. I've made an edit note to the original post. But good point, thanks.

Comment: I guess you've missed `counter = 0` in else case. It works as expected with it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `setTimeout` seems to fire infinity, is that it actually fires as many times as there is e.g. new elements added to the DOM. So basically, it assigns 3 `setTimeout` calls if 3 divs are added to the DOM. The reason being, that you are doing it inside `mutations.forEach(function(mutation) { ... }` loop.

Therefore, the solution is to remove the loop and only assign one `setTimeout` call at higher level which will fire when the DOM changes:

```
// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {

   // fired when a mutation occurs
   timer = setTimeout(function () {

      console.log("executed");
      // my_procedure();

   }, 500);  

});
```

Below is the full example, it should display "executed" once (after 3 second) to console when the DOM is actually changed, even though we add 3 new divs.

**[js fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/xbEB8/5/)**

**The code:**

```
// select the target node
var target = document.body,
    timer;

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {

   // fired when a mutation occurs
   timer = setTimeout(function () {

      console.log("executed");
      // my_procedure();

   }, 500);  

});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);

// Testing our observer
setTimeout(function() {
    document.body.innerHTML =  "<div>lol 1</div>";
    document.body.innerHTML += "<div>lol 2</div>";
    document.body.innerHTML += "<div>lol 3</div>";
}, 3000);

/* Comment out if you want to add more divs..
setTimeout(function() {
    document.body.innerHTML += "<div>lol 4</div>";
    document.body.innerHTML += "<div>lol 5</div>";
    document.body.innerHTML += "<div>lol 6</div>";
}, 5000);
*/
```

Cheers.

Comment: That makes perfect sence, I honestly don't know why I've made it so complicated - my_procedure evaluates the whole DOM anyway.

Comment: @dakov no problem, I noticed while debugging that you might have nested too deep the actual setTimeout check using mutation.addedNodes.length :) That's why it is worth to simplify as it is known without doing so with the callback in the first place. I would suggest that use mutations.forEach loop only if you really need to know more about the elements you have added.

Comment: @dakov and please, accept as answer or ask for clarification if something still bothers you, I updated my answer to tell a reason what was the problem with your code in the first place. :)

Comment: I'm sorry for delay, I was checking other answers. Your solution really simplified my code and really works with logging message - but doesn't work with `my_procedure` in this case it keeps firing repeatedly "executed" message (There must be some additional DOM manipulating within the function (sadly I don't know). But @V31 's example works even in this case. That's why I have to accept his answer, even though I feel sorry, that I can't accept both.

Answer (score 0):

You have got only 1 var "timer" and then you use ".forEach()" on your "mutations" !

So you overwrite timer each time, that's why if you set clearTimeout in my_procedure it doesn't work (it will stop only 1 timer, the last of the mutations).

Doesn't it ?