# timer to give alert when times end

Tags: javascript, timer, countdowntimer

I made a countdown timer. It will give alert/popup when times is up.
I wrote code like this :

```
function cd(){
now = new Date();
diff = end - now;
diff = new Date(diff);
var sec = diff.getSeconds();
var min = diff.getMinutes();

if(now >= end)
    {
    clearTimeout(timerID);

    window.alert("Time is up. Press OK to continue.");
    document.forms[0].submit();
    }
    else
    {
    document.getElementById("cdtime").innerHTML =  min + ":" + sec;
    }
    timerID = setTimeout("cd()", 10); 
}
window.onload = cd
```

This is auto submit timer. When time is up it will submit the form. The problem is that when I do `window.alert` it will keep alert even I click "`ok`". what should I do to make after I click ok it will redirect to the `document.forms[0].submit()` ?

Comment: You know that 10 is milliseconds and not seconds, right?

Comment: Can you post the whole "cd" function?

Comment: ok i already edit the code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `timerID = setTimeout("cd()", 10);` is always executed in your code. It should be inside the else block. Also there is no need to clear the timeout

(if you use `setInterval()` function instead of `setTimeout()` you will have to clear interval)...

Try this.

```
function cd(){
    now = new Date();
    diff = end - now;
    diff = new Date(diff);
    var sec = diff.getSeconds();
    var min = diff.getMinutes();

    if(now >= end)
        {
        window.alert("Time is up. Press OK to continue.");
        document.forms[0].submit();
        }
    else
        {
        document.getElementById("cdtime").innerHTML =  min + ":" + sec;
        setTimeout("cd()", 10); 
        }
    }
window.onload = cd;
```

Comment: thanks bro..it gave me better view in using timer.really help me a lot even window.alert not show. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (window.confirm(‘put stuff here’)) {
window.location.href=‘put link here’;
}
else {
var x = "";
}
```

Comment: i can't do window.location because i want to auto submit form

Answer (score 0):

Your timer fires every 10 miliseconds, so the alert is actually refreshing,

[setTimeout keeps firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908354/settimeout-keeps-firing)

read this, to give you a better idea, hope that helps

Comment: Also now that I see your function CD() You should have variables named

     var now = new Date();

etc etc.